# Printing Hamming (7,4) code for all possible 4-bit messages

Tags: c

I am trying to print the [Hamming (7,4) code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)) in C for all possible 4 bit messages. I have built for loops to cycle between all possible values of the four variables, but I am unsure of how to continue. I am trying to use the XOR operator in C to check for odd/even parity, but I am not unable to express the encoding in a program. I have the following C program till now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d; 
    int result;
    int p1,p2,p3;

    printf(" A B C D| OUT \n");
    printf("------------|-----\n");
    /* cycle through all input bit combinations */ 

    for ( a = 0; a <= 1; a = a + 1 )
    {
        for ( b = 0; b <= 1; b = b + 1 ) {
            for ( c = 0; c <= 1; c = c + 1 ) {
                for ( d = 0; d <= 1; d = d + 1 ) {
                    //unsure of how to compute p1, p2, p3 to print the Hamming (7,4) code
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I would be very grateful for any help with this!

Comment: The code you posted is just a few loops, it does nothing to do with the core problem, so it still looks like homework with little effort to me.

Comment: Instead of looping in 4 loops in range (0-1), you can combine this to a single loop in range (0-15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p1 covers d1, d2, d4 (a, b and d in your code) 
p2 covers d1, d3, d4
p3 covers d2, d3, d4.

If data bits are d1, d2, d3, d4, the hamming code would be

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 0|p1|p2|d1|p3|d2|d3|d4|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

<sup>(No leading zero is required if you are outputting in binary)</sup>
You can read [this tutorial](http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/bit-byte.html) to understand how to combine multiple bits into a byte if you need it.

One hint for coding:

```
p1 = a ^ b ^ d;
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps me understand the code better. I was able to implement it logically but was having trouble with framing the XOR statements in C.

Comment: Also, do I initialize the parity bits with some value?

Comment: You don't need to initialize the parity bits. Things only need to be initialized if you are using their value - in your example, you are setting p1 to a value calculated from d1, d2 and d4, so it doesn't matter what value p1 was to start with.